# Check Oracle database is open and ready

Tags: oracle, powershell, oracle19c

First of all. Of course I tried to google and have seen other answers, but none of them did help me.

**The problem**
I startup a server, and when it is started I want to plug a PDB.
To wait for DB to be initialized and open before I plug new PDB I run the script:

```
for (; ; )
{
    $process = Start-Process "sqlplus" -ArgumentList "-S sys/Qq123456 as sysdba @$Env:INSTALL_DIR\$Env:SCRIPT_DIR\ping.sql" -Wait -PassThru 

    if ($process.ExitCode -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Output "DB started!"
        break;
    }

    Start-Sleep -s 1
}
```

ping.sql:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;

declare
    db_not_open exception;
    pragma exception_init (db_not_open, -20123);
    l_count number(10);
begin
    select count(*) into l_count from v$instance where status = 'OPEN' and database_status = 'ACTIVE';
    if (l_count = 0) then
        RAISE db_not_open;
    end if;
end;
/

exit 0;
```

Then I try to plug PDB
`sqlplus -S / as sysdba "@$Env:INSTALL_DIR\$Env:SCRIPT_DIR\attach_pdb.sql"`
attach_pdb.sql:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;

create pluggable database test_pdb using 'c:\data\oracle\oradata\orcl\test_pdb\test_pdb.xml' nocopy tempfile reuse;
alter pluggable database test_pdb open;

exit;
```

So I loop until I have DB status open and active, but still sometimes I get an error when I'm trying to plug PDB:

```
create pluggable database test_pdb using 'c:\data\oracle\oradata\orcl\test_pdb\test_pdb.xml' nocopy tempfile reuse
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01109: database not open
```

So, who to check that the DB is open and ready to any operation?

Comment: What is the Oracle version?

Comment: @wolφi I have latest Oracle version c19 ee

Comment: While not an answer to your question, would this address your problem? `ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE test_pdb SAVE STATE;`

Comment: @wolφi it is not the case for me. I use windows docker with oracle db installed. On start I'm trying to download an instance of PDB and attach it to do some tests on it. So each time it is completely new server with oracle installed and I just wait until it is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the right solution, but I solved this using this ping script:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;

declare
    db_not_open exception;
    pragma exception_init (db_not_open, -20123);
    l_count number(10);
begin
    select count(*) into l_count from v$instance where status = 'OPEN' and database_status = 'ACTIVE';
    if (l_count = 0) then
        RAISE db_not_open;
    end if;

-- we have to be sure that simple operation is already possible
    execute immediate '
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE ping_pdb ADMIN USER ping_user identified by ping
DEFAULT TABLESPACE USERS
DATAFILE ''C:\data\oracle\oradata\ORCL\ping_pdb\users01.dbf''
SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON
FILE_NAME_CONVERT=(
    ''C:\data\oracle\oradata\ORCL\pdbseed'',
    ''C:\data\oracle\oradata\ORCL\ping_pdb\''
)';
    execute immediate 'drop pluggable database ping_pdb INCLUDING DATAFILES';
end;
/

exit 0;
```

It is not a good solution, but I have no ideas. If anyone have better solutions, please let me know.